# Where can I find information for learning to use Cisco IOS?

Tags: router, setup

I just purchased a Cisco 881 router for my business. I understand a little IOS but i'm having a little problem setting up the router to match the current router (dinky netgear personal router).

My plan is to first match the functionality of the current router:

- dhcp
- static outside ip
- port forwarding

...and then add additional functionality after it is in place:

- wpa wifi
- vpn
- Qos for my 3 ip phones

If anyone has a good site or any words of wisdom I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not [start at the source](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/access/800/860-880-890/software/configuration/guide/860-880-890SCG.html) and ask questions if you run into problems or don't understand something?

Comment: Wow. Not sure who gave you the downvote, but I agree with you fully. +1

Comment: +1 I've previously used the CISCO web site to answer my questions - it did take a bit of digging, but it was free! (I don't understand the downvote either.)

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine ended up buying the [Cisco IOS Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527228/) to get our Cisco hardware up and running.

Comment: +1 for the Cisco IOS Cookbook!  It's saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded some books